# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_effects.buffers.expanding')

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I'm getting an error when tried to copy&paste [this](https://github.com/Cierpliwy/SensorTag) solution in my app.

[image]

**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'effects.buffers.expanding')**

My code is pretty similar:

```
export function* handleBleState() {
  const {
    bleConnections: { manager },
  } = yield select()

  const stateChannel = yield eventChannel((emit) => {
    const subscription = manager.onStateChange((state) => {
      emit(state)
    }, true)
    return () => {
      subscription.remove()
    }
  }, buffers.expanding(1))

  try {
    for (;;) {
      const newState = yield take(stateChannel)
      const power = newState === 'PoweredOn'
      yield put(BLEActions.updateBleState(power))
    }
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      stateChannel.close()
    }
  }
}
```

But what is more strange is that I have extracted code from the [documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html) of redux-saga and the error is similar.
I replaced part of the code with this:

```
  const stateChannel = yield eventChannel((emitter) => {
    const iv = setInterval(() => {
      secs -= 1
      if (secs > 0) {
        emitter(secs)
      } else {
        // this causes the channel to close
        emitter(END)
      }
    }, 1000)
    // The subscriber must return an unsubscribe function
    return () => {
      clearInterval(iv)
    }
  })
```

And I get:

**undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0, _effects.eventChannel)')**

I'm using another version of redux-saga:

```
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
```

But I tried with the same version that he use

```
    "redux-saga": "0.16.2"
```

And then the issue is another one:

console.error: "unchaught at root", "at root at takeLatest" at handleBleState etc, etc.

[image]

Any help will be welcome, thanks in advance.

PD:

```
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^1.0.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `eventChannel` is nor part of the `effects` but defined directly in the main module, see the relevant [API doc](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events). So if you're using ES6 `import/export` you import it with the following statement:

```
import { eventChannel } from 'redux-saga'
```

While the `require` equivalent should be:

```
const eventChannel = require('redux-saga').eventChannel
```